Unable to start RDS replication to MariaDB RDS instance from AuroraDB for MySQL instance
I am following this guide in order to migrate MariaDB RDS instance into AuroraDB for MySQL.
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/migrate-self-managed-mariadb-to-amazon-aurora-mysql/
Reduce downtime associated with logical exports
In step 6 I ran in AuroraDB instance I got Fatal error during log purge, I have no idea what is wrong.
I continue to step 8 and I got Replica has encountered an error. Run SHOW REPLICA STATUS; to see the error.
When I run SHOW REPLICA STATUS; I got:
{
    "data":
    [
        {
            "Replica_IO_State": "",
            "Source_Host": "my-mariadb.xxxxxx.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com",
            "Source_User": "repl_user",
            "Source_Port": 3306,
            "Connect_Retry": 60,
            "Source_Log_File": "mysql-bin-changelog.024419",
            "Read_Source_Log_Pos": 245991,
            "Relay_Log_File": "relaylog.000002",
            "Relay_Log_Pos": 1716,
            "Relay_Source_Log_File": "",
            "Replica_IO_Running": "No",
            "Replica_SQL_Running": "No",
            "Replicate_Do_DB": "",
            "Replicate_Ignore_DB": "",
            "Replicate_Do_Table": "",
            "Replicate_Ignore_Table": "",
            "Replicate_Wild_Do_Table": "",
            "Replicate_Wild_Ignore_Table": "mysql.%",
            "Last_Errno": 13117,
            "Last_Error": "Could not find relay log file.",
            "Skip_Counter": 0,
            "Exec_Source_Log_Pos": 0,
            "Relay_Log_Space": 168667,
            "Until_Condition": "None",
            "Until_Log_File": "",
            "Until_Log_Pos": 0,
            "Source_SSL_Allowed": "No",
            "Source_SSL_CA_File": "",
            "Source_SSL_CA_Path": "",
            "Source_SSL_Cert": "",
            "Source_SSL_Cipher": "",
            "Source_SSL_Key": "",
            "Seconds_Behind_Source": null,
            "Source_SSL_Verify_Server_Cert": "No",
            "Last_IO_Errno": 13114,
            "Last_IO_Error": "Got fatal error 1236 from source when reading data from binary log: 'Failed to replace GTID event with backwards-compatible event: corrupt event.; the first event 'mysql-bin-changelog.024419' at 162661, the last event read from 'mysql-bin-changelog.024419' at 245991, the last byte read from 'mysql-bin-changelog.024419' at 246037.'",
            "Last_SQL_Errno": 13117,
            "Last_SQL_Error": "Could not find relay log file.",
            "Replicate_Ignore_Server_Ids": "",
            "Source_Server_Id": 1235731222,
            "Source_UUID": "",
            "Source_Info_File": "mysql.slave_master_info",
            "SQL_Delay": 0,
            "SQL_Remaining_Delay": null,
            "Replica_SQL_Running_State": "",
            "Source_Retry_Count": 86400,
            "Source_Bind": "",
            "Last_IO_Error_Timestamp": "240417 12:41:55",
            "Last_SQL_Error_Timestamp": "240417 12:41:55",
            "Source_SSL_Crl": "",
            "Source_SSL_Crlpath": "",
            "Retrieved_Gtid_Set": "",
            "Executed_Gtid_Set": "",
            "Auto_Position": 0,
            "Replicate_Rewrite_DB": "",
            "Channel_Name": "",
            "Source_TLS_Version": "",
            "Source_public_key_path": "",
            "Get_Source_public_key": 0,
            "Network_Namespace": ""
        }
    ]
}

I have tried to search a few error messages and have no solution at all.

Could you add the output of show slave status to your question.

@thecarpy JSON is the output of SHOW SLAVE STATUS from the new AuroraDB instance. I can post the output from original MariaDB replica

It was there in front of me - sorry, need more coffee.

Replication failed:
From the docs:

The Last_IO_Errno field shows that the instance is receiving I/O error 1236. The Source_Log_File field shows that the file name is mysql-bin-changelog.012345, which means that the log file index is 12345. To resolve the error, you can call mysql.rds_next_source_log with the following parameter:

CALL mysql.rds_next_source_log(12345);

In your case it is 24419, so:
CALL mysql.rds_next_source_log(24419);

Try that to use next source log.
You will have to double check that you are not missing any data, this can result in dataloss.

Thank you very much for helping. However I got Replica is down or disabled. once I run CALL mysql.rds_next_source_log(24419);. Do you have any idea what I should run to fix it?

You have to run that on the replica (AuroraDB). I would start over, if you get the same, read the error message (1236), run that immediately and try again.

Yes I am running it on the AuroraDB after setting its external source to the original master DB using MariaDB
